# how to submit a button tag via formaction attribute

Tags: html, css

I have created a html button & set the action via "formaction" attribute but I wonder why the button does not work at all!
This is my code: [click to see](http://pastebin.com/pxL3BxWe)
I'm actually new to web programming so please help me with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work that way. For forms to work, you have to have a `<form>` tag around it.

```
<form action="" method="post">
 <button type="submit" name="submit" class="button">Rate</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**MDN's docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) states:

> **formaction HTML5**
> The URI of a program that processes the information submitted by the button. If specified, it overrides the action attribute of the button's form owner.

Note that it *overrides* the action of the *button's form owner*, so you need to place the button inside a form in order for the formaction attribute to work.